# Spring boot YML SFTP configuration

Tags: spring, spring-boot, yaml, sftp

I am  working on a spring batch application using spring boot and yaml configurations.We have a requirement to SFTP the files to the same host name with 6 different userids.Each userid will redirect to a different root structure.

I am looking for a best practice to implement this, here is the options currently I am considering

1.Every time get a dynamic on demand jsch session by passing userid 2.Loading all the 6 different session on the startup using tasklet for each session.

Please let me know the other options to implement this

Comment: I am thinking to get new Jsch session object everytime by passing the user id and password try {
   session = ssh.getSession(this.userId, host, 22);
   session.setConfig(config);
   session.setPassword(this.accessId);
   session.connect();
   channel = session.openChannel("sftp");
   channel.connect();
   sftp = (ChannelSftp) channel;
  }

Comment: Just curious if creating a jsch session everytime for each user will impcat performance